# How to map JSON object with slashes in field name?

Tags: java, json, api, rest, gson

I am self-learned beginner in Java coding so please be understanding.
I am writing REST api app that at some point expects to get such response from server:

```
[
    {
        "success": {
            "/config/linkbutton": true
        }
    }
]
```

Normally I would create specific object with field named after my expected response and I would map this response to array of this objects which I could use later in my app. Although in this case I cannot do this, because I can't of course put slashes in the name of field in class.
So my question is how can I map this response to some object? Or maybe there can be another approach to use data provided in this response without creating object? I usually use gson to convert JSON to/from objects, but I am opened for all the solutions.

Will be grateful for anything that can put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/config/linkbutton` cannot, as you correctly point out, be used as a field name in Java. That is why serialization libraries typically have some way to separate the JSON name from the Java name. In GSON, this is done through the [SerializedName](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation; in Jackson, the [JsonProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation is used, and so on.

In your case, you could create an object with the following field:

```java
@SerializedName("/config/linkbutton")
boolean configLinkbutton;
```